# How to use ARCore and ARkit in content page of the xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, arkit, arcore

I want to implement augmented reality with xamarin forms. I found ARKit and ARCore library for xamarin.ios and xamarin.android respectively.

Can I use these both library in my PCL class library of xamarin.forms?

Can I integrate my page (layout or activity or UIViewController) to content page of my xamarin.forms?

Does renderer help to achieve the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use these both library in my PCL class library of xamarin.forms?

Most likely you **can't**. `ARKit` should be a native iOS library and `ARCore` is an *Android library* (Java)

> Can I integrate my page (layout or activity or UIViewController) to content page of my xamarin.forms?

As far as I know *not directly*. You will need a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) that will create the native view for your Xamarin.Forms view.

I'd suggest to have a look at [Customizing a ContentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage/).

The basic method is

- Create a page type that is derived from `ContentPage`
- Create custom renderers for each platform
- Implement the `OnElementChanged` method
- Create the native view
- Add the native view with `SetElement`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean to say that I can use ARKit and ARCore component in content page render class right?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've neant